# How to find the minimum path with the highest sum of edge weights?

Tags: algorithm, graph, fortran, dijkstra, path-finding

I'm trying to implement a modified Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path with highest weighted value between all nodes of an undirected graph.

My problem is that I don't know how to properly change my original Fortran code (that finds the minimum path with the lowest weight value). I would like to ask if you could help me with ideas to revise this code, mainly the subroutines *find_nearest* and *update_mind*, as well the code to run all over the nodes.

```
   c     ***************************************************************************
          subroutine dijkstra (nmols, matrixS)
          implicit none
          include 'COMMONP.dat'
          integer nmols, i, j, k1, k2, step, md, mv
          logical connected(nmols)
          integer, parameter :: i4_huge = 2147483647
          dimension mind(nmolsp), ohd(nmolsp, nmolsp)
    c
          ohd(1:nmols,1:nmols) = i4_huge
    c
          do i = 1, nmols
             ohd(i,i) = 0
          end do
    c
    c     Loading the weighted matrix
    c
          do 14 k1 = 1, nmols
             do 15 k2 = 1, nmols
                  if matrixS(k1,k2).ne.0 then
                  ohd(k1,k2) = matrixS(k1,k2)
     15   continue
     14   continue
    c
    c     carry out the algorithm
    c     start out with only node 1 connected to the tree.
    c
          do 33 node = 1, nmols
             connected(1:nmols) = .false.
             connected(node) = .true.
    c
    c     initialize the minimum distance to the one-step distance
    c
          mind(1:nmols) = ohd(node,1:nmols)
    c
    c     attach one more node on each interaction
           do step = 1, nmols
           call find_nearest (nmols, mind, connected, md, mv)

            if ( mv == -1 ) then
               write ( *, '(a)' )  ' '
               write ( *, '(a)' )  'DIJKSTRA_DISTANCE - Warning!'
               write ( *, '(a)' )  '  Search terminated early.'
               write ( *, '(a)' )  '  Graph might not be connected.'
               return
             end if
    c
    c     Mark this node as connected
    c
            connected(mv) = .true.
    c
    c      Having determined the minimum distance to node MV, see 
    c      what is the highest weighted path to other nodes.
    c
            call update_mind ( nmols, connected, ohd, mv, mind )

          end do

    !      Print the results.
    !
          write ( *, '(a)' )  ' '
          write ( *, '(a)' )  '  Minimum path from node i:'
          write ( *, '(a)' )  ' '
          do i = 1, nmols
            write ( *, '(2x,i2,2x,i2)' ) i, mind(i)
          end do
     33   continue
    !
          stop
          end

    c     ***************************************************************************
          subroutine find_nearest (nmols, mind, connected, md, mv)
          implicit none
          integer ( kind = 4 ) nmols
          logical ( kind = 4 ) connected(nmols)
          integer ( kind = 4 ) d
          integer ( kind = 4 ) i
          integer ( kind = 4 ), parameter :: i4_huge = 2147483647
          integer ( kind = 4 ) mind(nmols)
          integer ( kind = 4 ) v

          d = i4_huge
          v = -1

          do i = 1, nmols
            if ( .not. connected(i) .and. mind(i) < d ) then
              d = mind(i)
              v = i
            end if
          end do

          return
          end
    c     ***************************************************************************
          subroutine update_mind ( nmols, connected, ohd, mv, mind )
          implicit none
          integer ( kind = 4 ) nmols
          logical ( kind = 4 ) connected(nmols)
          integer ( kind = 4 ) i
          integer ( kind = 4 ), parameter :: i4_huge = 2147483647
          integer ( kind = 4 ) mind(nmols)
          integer ( kind = 4 ) mv
          integer ( kind = 4 ) ohd(nmols,nmols)

          do i = 1, nmols
            if ( .not. connected(i) ) then
   c
              if ( ohd(mv,i) < i4_huge ) then
                if ( mind(mv) + ohd(mv,i) < mind(i) ) then
                  mind(i) = mind(mv) + ohd(mv,i)
                end if
              end if
            end if
          end do

          return
          end
    c
```

Comment: The code is in some parts written in a really old style, much harder to read  for any people that might be willing to help. The problem is that for knowing how to change your code one first have to understand the code and that is a lot of effort to be asked from people here.

Comment: I thought I saw a similar question before but cannot find it anymore. I advised there that it might be more suitable for the stack sites "Code review" or "Operations Research".

Comment: I didn't look into the code, but did you investigate the possibility to negate the original weights in the input?